# Return anonymous functions

Tags: php, function, return-value, anonymous-function

I want to have a function written in PHP which can create anonymous functions which ~5 parameters and return them so I can store them in a key/value array and call them later without any knowledge about the parameters given and more than once.

E.g.

```
$fun();
```

How do I achieve the returning and the reusable calling afterwards?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you mean a static function or dynamic function? this might help http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php

Comment: you need PHP5.3 closures

Comment: Yes. I have a fun like 

$fun = function($p1, $p2, $p3 ..) {
magic stuff;
};

And i want to get rid of the calling with

$fun("foo", "bar", "bazz");

so I want a function to create functions like it is in erlang that i can call it with $short();

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
<?php
function setData($user, $pass, $host){
  return function() use ($user, $pass, $host){
    return array($user, $pass, $host);
  };
}

//set the data once
$container = setData('test', 'password', 'localhost');
//use the function without passing the data again (and it should be noted, you
//can't set the data again)
var_dump($container());
```

And the output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "test"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "password"
  [2]=>
  string(9) "localhost"
}
```

Not sure of your use case, but for my example the output of the function could be a formatted DNS as well as the simple arrays.

As mentioned elsewhere, [func_get_args](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) would make this work with any number of arguments.

Comment: I think that is it and phpunit says that it works, too! Thanks for the fast and fitting answer ;)

Comment: Can you run the anonymous function without saving it to a variable? i.e. `setData('test','password','localhost')()`?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

```
$greet = function($name)
{
    printf("Hello %s\r\n", $name);
};

$greet('World');
$greet('PHP');
```

The `$greet` variable could be returned by another function if you need.

The other thing you might need to look at is [`func_get_args()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) for reading the arbitrary argument list.